# Plotly: How to customize axis transformation?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to do some customized axis transformation to show my data better in a plot by Plotly Python. For example, using `x1 = ln(x)`, `y1 = ln(ln(1-y))` to make the original `y=1-exp(x^3)` curve linear. I'd like to know whether Plotly supports such a customized axis transformation (I failed to find it in the documentation), or I have to do the data transformation first, then make the plot and customize ticks? What is the best practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, specifying a custom axis type is not possible at the moment. From the docs you can see that the axis type can be specified as:

> ```
>   - One of the following enumeration values:
>         ['-', 'linear', 'log', 'date', 'category',
>         'multicategory']
> ```

So I would definitely do the necessary transformations before plotting in your case.